# mod_rewrite does not working while trying to hide .php extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

how properly can I hide .php extensions form my url : example:

```
www.example.com/index.php
```

to

```
www.example.com/index
```

My .htaccess file content is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

And it is not working although phpinfo() shows that mod_rewrite is in "Loaded Modules" section. What's wrong here?

---

When I tried to set Authentication:

```
AuthUserFile /usr/home/vesa/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName Somewhere Neat
AuthType Basic

<Limit GET POST>
require user vesa
</Limit>
enter code here
```

It asked for username and password. Therefore I assume that .htaccess files are processed by server. Right?

---

When I try to add

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
```

I get `500 Internal Server Error`

---

When I add `RewriteRule (.*)\.asp $1.php` it successfully changes any .asp extension to .php

---

When I use RewriteRule it just redirects my browser to another file. So in case if I will try to hide extension it should redirect me to file with no extension - in which case I will get error because there is no such file exists. What is the simplest way to make mod_rewrite "hide" (write url filenames without extension .php) while linking to .php files?

Comment: Try changing it to this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]`.  Maybe you have some rules after this that are messing it up?

Comment: No, It is whole content of my .htaccess. What [L] stands for? It don't work either.

Comment: `[L]` tells htaccess that that's the last rule and to stop checking after it hits that rule.

Comment: Your `phpinfo()`'s loaded modules should not list server modules AFAIK. `mod_rewrite` is a server module, so I wonder it's displayed there. Can you add a screenshot to your question so it's clear what you write about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, there is some configuration set that allows (for .htaccess file) to redirect to any file, it is basically rewrite URL, but in the same time it is not allowing `Options +FollowSymlinks`. I'm not familiar with php config file, but i am sure system administrators knows what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Is your PHP file sending a redirect to force the user to index.php? Use something like firebug to see what's going on in the headers.